# Creating a pandas dataframe from a dictionnary and with different types of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am really not used to pandas, thus the question on how to resolve this problem:

I have a dictionary called `table` which is similar to:

```
table = dict()
table[(1, 1)] = [1000, (1.05, 1.02), [Class1(1.05), Class1(1.02)]]
table[(2, 3)] = [3400, (1.8, 2.9), [Class1(1.8), Class1(2.9)]]
table[(4, 5, 5)] = [2800, (4, 5.2, 5.1), [Class1(4), Class1(5.2), Class1(5.1)]]
```

In this layout of the input, a custom class, called `Class1` is used. This class is not relevant to the pandas dataframe since it will be lost in the transfer from the dictionary to the dataframe. The output dataframe I am looking for only contains 3 columns: `key`, `replacement key` and `integer` where `key` is the dictionary key, `replacement key` is the second value of the list and `integer` is the first value of the list.

```
Index          key             Replacement key        Integer
1              (1, 1)          (1.05, 1.02)           1000
2              (2, 3)          (1.8, 2.9)             3400
3              (4, 5, 5)       (4, 5.2, 5.1)          2800
```

At the moment, I was trying to create an empty dataframe and to fill it line by line. However, I failed to access and replace each line.

```
headers = ['Key','Integer', 'Replacement key']
index = range(1, len(table)+1)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=headers)
```

In the end, I would also like to export this dataframe into a .csv format (to open and customize with excel).

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(table, orient='index').reset_index().iloc[:,:3]
df.columns =['Key','Integer', 'Replacement key']
# swap the column integer and replacement key
df = df[['Key','Replacement key','Integer']]
print(df)

# export .csv
df.to_csv('test.csv')


         Key Replacement key  Integer
0     (1, 1)    (1.05, 1.02)     1000
1     (2, 3)      (1.8, 2.9)     3400
2  (4, 5, 5)   (4, 5.2, 5.1)     2800
```

**Explain**

`from_dict()` converts the key of the dictionary to the index of each row when `orient='index'`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(table, orient='index')
print(df)
              0              1                                                  2
(1, 1)     1000   (1.05, 1.02)  [<__main__.Class1 object at 0x7f0f270b6940>, <...
(2, 3)     3400     (1.8, 2.9)  [<__main__.Class1 object at 0x7f0f270b69e8>, <...
(4, 5, 5)  2800  (4, 5.2, 5.1)  [<__main__.Class1 object at 0x7f0f270c19b0>, <...
```

So `Reset_index()` is used to release keys as columns. `iloc` is used to keep the first three columns, because you don't need Class1 columns.